# PHP RegEx is being parsed 2 times

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a PHP script that takes a plain text file task list and parses things like:

- Project name heading because it ends with a semi-colon: == a project
- Tasks begin with a `- task name`
- @tag-name gets wrapped with `<span class="tag">@tag-name</span>`
- @done gets wrapped with `<span class="tag done">@done</span>`
- and more

This PHP function below is what does the replacements...

```
function get_marked_up_todo($todo){
    $todo = htmlspecialchars($todo,ENT_QUOTES)."\n\n";
    $search = array('/(.+:)(.+)\n\n/sU',     // Get projects
                    '/(- ([^\@\n]+).+)/',    // Get todos
                    '/(.+:)/',               // Get headings
                    '/\n([^\<\n].+)/',       // Get notes
                    '/- (.+@done)/',         // Get done
                    '/(@due\([^\)]+\))/',    // Get due tags
                    '/(@(?!due)[^\s]+)/',    // Get tags
                    "/\t/",
                    '/`(.*?)`/',             // inline code
                    );
    $replace = array("<div class=\"project\">\n$1$2\n</div>\n\n",
                    '<span class="todo"><input type="checkbox" value="'.trim('\2').'"> \1</span>',
                    '<h1>\1</h1>',
                    "\n\t<span class=\"note\">$1</span>",
                    '<span class="bullet-done">? ? ??</span> - <strike>\1</strike>',
                    '<span class="tag due">\1</span>',
                    '<span class="tag">\1</span>',
                    "\t<span class=\"tab\"></span>",
                    '<code>\1</code>',
                    );
    return preg_replace($search, $replace, $todo);
}
```

---

In the above search and replace arrays the very last item in both arrays is a new pattern I added to find inline code wrapped in backticks like Markdown inline code.

The problem is, on the output each task item row gets a checkbox input field added to the front of the task row and in the value of this checkbox my code is being parsed.

All the other replacement RegEx does not show up in the checkbox values only when I add an item like this inline code or any other item I have added such as RegEx for bold text and italic.

Why does mine show up in the checkbox value HTML and none of the others do?

I have setup a demo to show the output here of the PHP -
 https://3v4l.org/f0e8W#output

---

Here is the full code as well

```
<?php
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>TODO.todo</title></head>
<body>
<style>
.project {
    line-height: 4px;
}
.bullet-done {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    color: rgba(0,114,62,1.0);
}
.note{
display: block;
color: rgba(133,130,102,1.0);
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
.todo {
    display: inline-block;
}
.tag {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    color: rgba(160,46,43,0.6);
}
body {
    background: rgba(239,233,183,1.0);
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.31);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
    color: rgba(188,100,74,1.0);
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 34px;
}
.tab{
    display: inline-block;
    width:0px;
    height: 0px;
    background: #000000;
</style><pre>";
$todo = 'Version 1:
This file is in TaskPaper format.
Tabs are used to indent.
    Each task begins with a "- ".
Projects end with a ":".
Tags are in the format "@tag_name".
All other lines (such as these) are considered as notes,
and are to be ignored.

- User signup
- Register for an account
    - Log in @done
    - Forget password

- Manage users
    - Create users @in_progress
    - Delete users
    - User profile page @40%

- Blog
    - Creating new posts @done
    - Comments @done
    - Moderating comments @done

This is my todo list:
    This is a note about the list.
    - this is an item  @done
    - and this is @me 
this is a note about my done item
  - this is the last @java @shopping @item @done

This is a second list:
- Add more funk to something @work @java 
    - Send something somewhere @work @email @due(12 Aug 07)
        - this is an example
- dfgdfg
ggg
hfghf  
- hgh
- dfygdfgdf

List:
- gdfgdf `inline code` hhf
- gdfgdf
- dfgdfg @done
        ';

echo get_marked_up_todo($todo);

echo '</pre></body></html>';

function get_marked_up_todo($todo){
    $todo = htmlspecialchars($todo,ENT_QUOTES)."\n\n";
    $search = array('/(.+:)(.+)\n\n/sU',     // Get projects
                    '/(- ([^\@\n]+).+)/',    // Get todos
                    '/(.+:)/',               // Get headings
                    '/\n([^\<\n].+)/',       // Get notes
                    '/- (.+@done)/',         // Get done
                    '/(@due\([^\)]+\))/',    // Get due tags
                    '/(@(?!due)[^\s]+)/',    // Get tags
                    "/\t/",
                    '/`(.*?)`/',             // inline code
                    );
    $replace = array("<div class=\"project\">\n$1$2\n</div>\n\n",
                    '<span class="todo"><input type="checkbox" value="'.trim('\2').'"> \1</span>',
                    '<h1>\1</h1>',
                    "\n\t<span class=\"note\">$1</span>",
                    '<span class="bullet-done">? ? ??</span> - <strike>\1</strike>',
                    '<span class="tag due">\1</span>',
                    '<span class="tag">\1</span>',
                    "\t<span class=\"tab\"></span>",
                    '<code>\1</code>',
                    );
    return preg_replace($search, $replace, $todo);
}
```

Comment: Much unclear. You should explicitly add expected output while showing current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the issue correctly, your issue is that when you use your own replacement for `<code>`, the `<input>` tag looks like this:

`<input type="checkbox" value="gdfgdf <code>inline code</code> hh">`

but you want to it to NOT include the `<code>...</code>` part, like this:

`<input type="checkbox" value="gdfgdf ">`.

If my understanding is correct, then you fix you simply need to fix the RegExp that's in charge of rendering the `<input>` tag, which is this one:

`'/(- ([^\@\n]+).+)/',    // Get todos`

The way it works is by taking everything from `-` until either a `@` or a newline (`\n`) shows up. You want to add do it the backtick:

'/(- ([^\@\n]+).+)/',    // Get todos

This will make the RegExp stop capturing when it encounters the first ` and will fix your issue (again, if I understood it correctly).

Comment: Thanks I understand the cause of issue better now.  Ideally I would want to add RegEx for inline code, bold text, italic text, etc...these new types all wrap around a text and have a closing tag which the current regex does not have any patters with closing tags except this new code tag.  With these wrapping patterns they all would want the text after the pattern is found too so it sounds like maybe I should make a 2nd `todos` Regex to store the raw text in one and use it for the input value.  Thanks for the help

Comment: or maybe the `todo` regex could be modified to include the pattern for all these text styling patterns and have it all in 1 pattern for the todo and capture them to different capture groups

Comment: I would modify the todo regex to include all of them. It's clearer when you come back to it than having 2 different regex. If my answer solved your issue please mark is as such so we can all move on :)